# Disable validation for jaxb 1 marshaller

Tags: jaxb

How to disable the validation on marshaller for jaxb1?

Comment: What sort of validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set a ValidationEventHandler on your marshaller that ignored all the events:

```
marshaller.setEventHandler(new IgnoringValidationEventHandler());
```

The ValidationEventHandler would look something like:

```
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEvent;
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler;

public class IgnoringValidationEventHandler implements ValidationEventHandler {

    public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Note:**
If this is a new application I would recommend using JAXB 2 (JSR-222) instead of JAXB 1.

Comment: Failing to work with J8 against a local DTD, sadly.  many thanks however !